# How to pass object literals as polymer attributes

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

In order to test some polymer custom elements of mine in isolation, I would like to be able to pass in js object literals for some attributes that would ordinarily come from parent elements. I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this. See this example code. If it were working as I would like it to, it would display a 1 and a 2 next to each other, but it doesn't work.

```html
<script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/webcomponents.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="my-element" attributes="stuff">
  <template>
    {{stuff.one}} {{stuff.two}}
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('my-element', {
      ready: function () {
        console.log(this.stuff);
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
<my-element stuff='{"one": 1, "two": 2}'></my-element>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Polymer only converts the JSON text into an object, if you initialize the `stuff` property with an empty hash:

```
Polymer('my-element', {
    stuff: {},
    ready: function () {
        console.log(this.stuff);
    }
});
```

Without this, the `stuff` attribute is passed in as a string. The same goes for arrays.

Comment: Any idea how to do this without knowing the name of the attribute?

Comment: Don't add stuff: {} directly, but use the declared properties and default value feature. And, use a function that returns an object, otherwise all instances of your element will end up sharing the same object.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to do it:

*myElem.html*

```
<link rel="import"
      href="http://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/samples/components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="my-element">
    <template>
        <div> {{stuff.one}} {{stuff.two}} </div>
    </template>

    <script>
      Polymer({
          is: "my-element",
          properties: {
              stuff:{
                  type: Object,
                  value: {"one":"default_1","two":"default_2"}
              }
          }
      });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

---

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/samples/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="myElem.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <my-element></my-element>
    <my-element stuff={"one":"1","two":"2"}></my-element>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

*Result*

```
default_1 default_2  
1 2
```

Comment: basically repetition of the above but nice example.

Answer (score 3):

```
index.html
...
  <body unresolved fullbleed layout vertical>
     <my-post info='{"name":"Alex","id":"123"}' posts='[{"id":"456","name":"post1"},{"id":"789","name":"post2"}]'></my-post>  
  </body>
    ...

my-post.html 
    <link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <polymer-element name="my-post" attributes="info posts" >
      <template>

       {{info.name}}
         <template repeat="{{post in posts}}">
              <br>   {{post.id}} - {{post.name}}
         </template>

      </template>
   <script>
    (function () {
      Polymer({
      ready: function() {
        this.info=JSON.parse(this.info)
        this.posts=JSON.parse(this.posts)
    },
   });
  })();
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: Like this one as what I ended up basing my component on this explanation . +1